# How do you auto-input text into a password field? (Batch)

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

Part of my program's job is to create a new user account, elevate it to admin, and then run programs AS that user.

To do this, I would use the following code:

```
runas /user:hostname\AddedUserProfile /savecred program.exe
```

This works, but there is a problem. To use the `runas` command, the user you are running the program through, must have a password. Upon running the command, it asks you for that user's password. My program is supposed to run **behind the scenes**, and without the user being able to see it (Don't worry. I already have code that invisibly starts programs, so that is **NOT** the issue here). I can't find a way to automatically enter text into the password entry field (and yes, I know the password doesn't show visibly). I've tried having the program echo the password, and I've even tried to have it rerout the output of an echo command, into the input of the password field.

```
echo password | runas /user:hostname\AddedUserProfile /savecred program.exe
```

Even that doesn't work! it just gives me an error:

```
RUNAS ERROR: Unable to run - taskmgr.exe
-2147467259: Unspecified error
```

I really am at my wit's end on this one. If there is a way to do this other than runas, I'd LOVE to know! I'd prefer that it was using `runas`, though.

Edit:
It seems that the error is due to an incorrect password entry. I can't figure out why it would be entering it incorrectly, however. If I do not use the `/savecred`, then I get an error message that actually says that the password is incorrect.

Comment: `echo password |...` appends a space to the password. Try `echo password|...`

Comment: @Stephan I just tried that, but it gives me the same error. Upon further testing, I realized that it actually gives that error code, when the password is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Auto input password by using a pipe method like this:

```
echo PasswordHere | runas /user:hostname\AddedUserProfile /savecred program.exe
```

That mean, it will type "PasswordHere" when runas.exe need user input. I'm not tested it yet, so you have to try it out. I always use this "pipe" way to access my FTP server.

Comment: Just realized I misstyped (Forgot to put the pipe in the question body). I've been trying to use the pipe method, and it hasn't worked.